# how can pass data back from current screen to previous screen after clicking back button, ios

Tags: iphone, ios

I am transferring data from FirstView to SecondView after clicking on a button.

```
FirstView.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *stringOfFirstView;
```

> ```
> FirstView.m
>
>  - (void)pushToSecond {
>          SecondView *controller   =   [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
>          controller.stringOfSecondView          =   self.stringOfFirstView;
>          [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
>
>         }
> ```

In SecondView, I have

```
SecondView.h
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *stringOfSecondView;
```

At SecondView,my goal is to go back to FirstView by clicking on back button and also want assign `stringOfSecondView` to `stringOfFirstView` as well

**Question :**

```
How can I assign stringOfSecondView to stringOfFirstView via clicking back button.
```

Just let you know, I am detecting an click event on back button in SecondView by doing

```
SecondView.m
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self]==NSNotFound)
        NSLog(@"will show onto console");  

}
```

But I am stuck how to do passing data back

Please advice if you have any clues about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a delegate. So in your SecondView you need to create a protocol that sends data back to your FirstView. Your FirstView would become a delegate of the SecondView. There are tons of tutorials on how to make a delegate.

Comment: delegate is another option that you can send back data.I am also looking for another alternative way such as how to know the previous controller from uinavigation controller.....

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 2 options:

1. In `secondView`: hold a reference to `firstView`
2. The more flexibile alternative: If you possibliy want to reuse the functionality, define a 
   protocol. Let `firstView` implement this protocol, and let `firstView` be the delegate for
   `secondView`

In both cases, `secondView` will have an assign/weak-Property, where it stores a reference to `firstView`. And `firstView` will implement a Method, which receives a NSString and stores it in `stringOfFirstView`

Answer (score 0):

It might help not to think of it as assigning via the click of the back button. Essentially, when you click the back button your FirstView will regain control. At the point where it is back in control, you can simply ask SecondView for the value of stringOfSecondView and store it wherever you like, such as in stringOfFirstView.

In order to ask the SecondView for this information, you may want to "remember" who the SecondView is by storing it's ID in an instance variable in FirstView. Also, remember to retain and release it properly if you are not doing automatic reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement ttran's answer, you can take a look here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html.

The basic idea is to create a Protocol (where you define methods that should be implemented (optionally or not) by the classes that adopt this Protocol. This means that your FirstViewController can adopt a Protocol, so your Second View Controller can know some methods that the First View Controller has.

So, the missing part is that the Second View Controller needs to have a reference to the First View Controller. You can do that via delegation (The delegate usually is a weak property).

Again, you can read more and understand this process by reading the basics of protocol and delegates.